# implement javascript message in Code behind C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need a code segment to call a javascript function recordInserted() which shows up an alert, from my following code behind method,

```
protected void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String gradename = txt_gradename.Text;
        int allocatedclasses = Int32.Parse(txt_allocatedclasses.Text);
        String headid = txt_head_id.Text;
        int numberofstudents = Int32.Parse(txt_numberofstudents.Text);

        db = new DBConnection();
        db.getConnection();
        db.executeUpdateQuery("INSERT INTO Grade (GradeName,AllocatedClasses,GradeHeadID,NumberOfStudents) VALUES ('"+gradename+"','"+allocatedclasses+"','"+headid+"','"+numberofstudents+"')");

//I Need to call it from here before redirecting
        Response.Redirect("AdminReferenceGradeAdd.aspx");
    }
```

Please helpp me with this.

I have tried the following but never worked,

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"Call my function","recordInserted()",true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will never work .. beacuse you are saying to redirect.
when you say `Response.Redirect` every thing which you have prepared to send is not sent,instead response is redirect to a new page.So your client script never reaches to browser.
you can use it like this :-

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"Call my function","recordInserted();window.location.href='wwW.google.com'",true);
```

use window.location.href to redirect to your page("yourpage.aspx').

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Call your function", "recordInserted()", true);
```

Or try calling Javascript function after a second:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "Call your function", "setTimeout('recordInserted()', 1000)", true);
```

Comment: It didn't work, simply redirected to the aspx page without showing up the alert! :(

Comment: @DilukshanMahendra I've edited my answer. Can you try the second method, if have time?

Comment: Yeah! Dfntly, Thanks Aycan